# MySQL Store Procedure with IF Statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to define a mysql stored procedure that if you pass it a parameter, uses it in a select query and if you don't then it doesn't.

Here's what i have, and it's not working :

```
IF (selected_category IS NULL) then

SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name' 
FROM items i, categories c WHERE i.category_id = c.id;

ELSE IF (selected_category IS NOT NULL) then

SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name'
FROM items i, categories c WHERE i.category_id = c.id AND c.name LIKE selected_category;

END IF
```

I've also tried, instead of `ELSE IF`, to write `ELIF`, `END IF;` and then a new `IF` but nothing wants to work.

When I click the Create Procedure it always displays an error unless I comment out everything below the first `SELECT`.

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one query:

```
SELECT i.id, i.name, i.summary, i.description, i.location, c.name AS 'category_name'
FROM items i, categories c 
WHERE i.category_id = c.id 
AND IF(selected_category IS NOT NULL, c.name LIKE CONCAT('%', selected_category,'%'), TRUE);
```

On a side note, please use explicit joins instead of implicit.

ps: I realize I didn't really answer your question, I just provided an alternative. I think you just missed the `ELSEIF` statement. You are using `ELSE IF` and you tried `ELIF`, but it's [apparently not the correct syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html).

Comment: It worked as in that it accept the procedure and created it, but when i call the procedure, it always returns "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."